# Crear columnas de un gridview con TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy intentando hacer un gridview en el cual necesito agregar columnas dinámicamente, que contengan un TextBox en cada celda y que esos TextBox muestren los datos que obtengo de una BD, los datos ya los obtengo y los muestro en el grid, pero aun no hallo como hacer para agregar un TextBox en cada celda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres mostrar un textbox tienes que definir columnas del tipo `TemplateField`.

Puede hacerlo visualmente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O puedes hacerlo en el html:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NombreColumna">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NombreColumna") %>'></asp:TextBox>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

indicando el nombre de la columna con el cual mapea, aconsejo que las columnas las definas entiempo de diseño

---

Si es dinámico desde código deberás crear una clase que herede de `ITemplate` para poder crear la columna template

En el articulo explico sobre el tema

[[GridView] ITemplate – Columnas definidas en runtime](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2010/08/gridview-itemplate-columnas-definidas.html)

Se debe definir una clase que herede de `ITemplate`, luego tienes que asignar esta a las propiedades de TemplateField y agregarlo a la colección de Columns

```
TemplateField tempDesc = new TemplateField();
tempDesc.HeaderTemplate = new GridViewHeaderTemplate("Nombre Columna");
tempDesc.ItemTemplate = new GridViewItemTemplate("Nombre Columna");
tempDesc.EditItemTemplate = new GridViewEditTemplate("Nombre Columna");
GridView1.Columns.Add(tempDesc);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Leandro, exactamente era eso lo que necesitaba